# android : extract uk postcode

Tags: java, regex, string, matching

Hello I am trying to extract a uk postcode from a string i.e. "the person's house is at SS9 8ID we'll be there at 8pm" so I can extract the "SS9 8ID" bit. I've tried the following code but it's not working for some reason...any ideas???

```
        String pc1="^([A-PR-UWYZ](([0-9](([0-9]|[A-HJKSTUW])?)?)|([A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|[ABEHMNPRVWXY])?)) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})|GIR 0AA$";
        String test="the person's house is at SS9 8ID we'll be there at 8pm";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pc1);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test.toUpperCase());
        if (matcher.matches()) {
                //Log.d("pccode:::", matcher.group(1) );
            Log.d("pccode:::", matcher.group());
        } else { Log.d("NO","NO PCODE"); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `matches` method matches the whole string, you should use `find` instead. And don't use `^` and `$` in the expression.

Also the `SS9 8ID` doesn't match the regexp, because `ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z` doesn't include letter `I` which is in the postcode.

Comment: SS9 8ID isn't a valid UK postcode; I suspect it was made up for the question as an example, but if he's using it as an example to test with then it was a poor choice. The regex he's supplied looks like the official one (minus the overseas territories, military and other special codes), although I haven't checked it in detail. In short, if he uses a better test code, he'll have better luck (I use "TE57 1NG" as a test code, but using real valid codes would also be a good idea.

Comment: @user788971 the link I gave you has a lot of explanations and even a screen-shot.